Estimate on derivative of a curve knowing diameter and second derivative

I'm reading the paper "A continuation principle for periodic solution of forced motion equations on manifolds and applications to bifurcation theory" by M. Furi and M. P. Pera.
I'm not grasping the proof of Lemma 1.1.
Follows: the statement of the lemma, a screenshot of a part of the proof found in the paper (I need only an explanation on the first part of it), and what I don't get.


Lemma 1.1: Let $x:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^k$ a periodic $C^2$ curve. Let $u=\max\{|\dot x(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R}\}$,  $d=\max\{|x(t_1)-x(t_2)|: t_1,t_2 \in\mathbb{R}\}$  and $F=\max\{|\ddot x(t)| : t\in \mathbb{R}\}$.
Then
$$
u^2 \leq Fd
$$


Proof:

Comment to the proof:
Now, the problem I have with this proof is that I don't understand why we want to prove $\dot \varphi ^2(t) \leq Fd$. (Let me note that if I'm not mistaken, $\dot \varphi ^2 = (\frac{d}{dt} \varphi)^2$).
The following reasoning makes me think that we should rather try to prove that $\dot \varphi(t) \leq Fd$, without the square.
At the beginning of the proof we fix an arbitrary functional $\mu:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. We can represent this functional with some vector $\eta$ as the map $\xi\mapsto \eta\cdot \xi$.
We than define $\varphi(t) =\mu(x(t)) = \eta\cdot x(t)$. Its derivative becomes $\dot \varphi(t)= \eta\cdot\dot x(t)$.
Now, I believe that the reason for fixing an arbitrary functional is this:
Since we know that exists a $\hat{t}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u=|\dot x(\hat{t})|$, we have that $u^2=\dot x(\hat t) \cdot \dot x(\hat t)$. Hence $u^2=\hat \mu(\dot x(\hat t))$, $\hat \mu$ being the functional $\xi\mapsto \dot x(\hat t) \cdot \xi$.
But if we define here, in the same way as before, $\varphi = \hat \mu(x)$, we get that $u^2 = \dot\varphi(\hat t)$, not $u^2 = \dot\varphi(\hat t)^2$
I see that maybe I have chosen the wrong $\mu$ in the above reasoning, but I can't see any other choice. Note also that the square on $\dot\varphi$ is in fact used in the rest of the proof, and that nothing allows us to assume that $u\geq1$.
Anyhow I believe that the result is true, after all it makes sense, but I can't get a hold of this proof.
